# How to export raster of Mean Annual Land Surface Temp from Landsat Imagery?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, remote-sensing, google-earth, landsat-8

I am using google earth engine to estimate Mean Annual land surface temp of a local scale from 1984 to 2019 from landsat Imagery.
I am having trouble determining a script for my goal, there are many example but the problem is that all of them are calculating the LST for one year.
I have tried this script but I think there is some thing wrong with it and I cannot export the raster of calculated Mean annual LST for my study.
I will be helpful, if anybody could help me to rectify the script. [The GEE Code for Export raster of mean annual lsthere](https://code.earthengine.google.com/0bc544dd0048db04e713cd7f235e2309)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function calculating LST for a single year (you already have all the code for the function), invoke it for every year, finally combine the results to a single multi-band image.

```
function calculateLST(col) {
  // ...
}

var annualLST = ee.ImageCollection(
    years.map(function (year) {
        var colForYear = col.filter(
          ee.Filter.calendarRange(year, year, 'year')
        )
        return calculateLST(colForYear)
          .rename(ee.String('LST_')
          .cat(ee.Number(year).int()))
    })
  )
  .toBands() // Convert ImageCollection to a single image
  .regexpRename('.*_(LST.*)', '$1') // Get rid of 'n_' band name prefixes

Export.image.toDrive({
      image: annualLST,
      description: 'annualLST',
      scale: 30,
      region: geometry
    });
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/0bc544dd0048db04e713cd7f235e2309

Comment: Hi @Daniel thank you very much for your replay. My goal is just calculating the Mean Annual Land Surface Temp for each year separately, I am trying to export the raster images of  Mean Annual Land Surface Temp from 1984 to 2019 which is about 35 images. There is no need to combine all of annual rasters. My code is written for the yearly but It is not estimating Mean Annual Land Surface Temp.